# Cannot click button at bottom of page in React Native

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I cannot click a button or touchable opacity at the bottom of the page. We have to either move it to the top of the page or higher up.

Here's an example

```
import React, { useRef, createRef,useEffect } from "react";

import {ScrollView,Text,View,Image,Dimensions,StyleSheet,Animated, TouchableOpacity, BackHandler,Button} from 'react-native';

export default class TestButtonScreen extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){

        const TestButton=(event,id)=>{
                console.log("testbutton");

            }
            let deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
            let deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

        return (

                        <View>

                            <View style={{height:'90%' }}>
                            <Text> top of view</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{height: '10%' , paddingTop:10, marginTop: 0}}>

                           <Button
                                                          onPress={(event) => TestButton(event)} title="test button">
                                                    </Button>
                            </View>
                        </View>
            );
    }
}
```

I have tried different things such as:

- TouchableOpacity
- Pressable
- Button
- making View clickable with  onStartShouldSetResponder={() => {console.log('Clicked')}}
- zIndex . I made the button have a higher index than other components on the screen

Everything seems to have the same effect. Clicking at the bottom of the page does not register for the button unless I click the far left or right edge of the button.

I am using React Native 0.68.2. This appears to happen in android studio emulator and also the real device.

Answer (score 0):

We actually figured it out. It appears out our network provider utility was interfering with the rendered components.

This library : import { useNetInfo } from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

We had some `<View></View>` appear when the network connection was not live. Although our connection to the network was up, it still was getting in the way of the buttons it appears.